# Add a message to your HTTP 400 Bad Request in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, httprequest, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, bad-request

Is there a way I can add a message to a `BadRequest` action result, and for that message to be visible to external clients, such as Postman? I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Part of my code is included below. I want to say what the problem is—e.g., that the `id` sent in the body is not the same as the one taken from the URL. For now, I am using an `Error` object that I’ve made, which has the error code and message. But those aren't visible in Postman when I send the request.

```cs
public ActionResult PutColour(int id, Colour colour)
{
    if (id != colour.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest(new Error("IDNotTheSame","ID from URL is not the same as in the body."));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you pass to `BadRequest` is serialized and returned as the response body. If *nothing* is coming through, the only explanation is that you don't have any public properties on `Error` that can be serialized. For example, if you had something like:

```
public class Error
{
    public Error(string type, string description)
    {
        Type = type;
        Description = description;
    }

    public string Type { get; private set }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
}
```

Then, you get a response like:

```
{
    "type": "IDNotTheSame",
    "description": "ID from URL is not the same as in the body."
}
```

Not sure what your `Error` class currently does. However, this is probably unnecessary anyways, as you can just use `ModelState`:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Id", "ID from URL is not the same as in the body.");
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

Finally, it should probably be said that this is a pointless validation in the first place. You shouldn't be sending an id with the model at all (always use a view model, not an entity class), and even if you do send it, you can simply just overwrite it with the value from the URL:

```
model.Id = id;
```

Done. No issues and you don't need to worry about sending an error back.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Yes, the problem was that in my Error class I had attributes, not properties. Also, thanks for the extra information, very helpful. I will check the internet to see more about view models, but I understood the idea you wrote me

Comment: And I also want to say thank you to Jeremy Caney, who made the question more correct :) Don't know if this is the right place, but hey, I tried :)

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the following steps to show Bad Request with your custom Class.
Create constructor here of that class. And add manual description and many more

**Step 1**

Add a custom class and inherit this class with `ValidationProblemDetails`. After that initialize below base class constructor by passing `context.ModelState`.

`public ValidationProblemDetails(ModelStateDictionary modelState)`

Here is implementation-

```
public class CustomBadRequest : ValidationProblemDetails
    {
        public CustomBadRequest(ActionContext context) : base(context.ModelState)
        {
            Detail = "add details here";
            Instance = "add extension here";
            Status = 400;
            Title = "add title here";
            Type = "add type here";
        }
    }
```

**Step 2**

Add this Custom Bad request class in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.AddMvc().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
                {
                    var problems = new CustomBadRequest(context);

                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(problems);
                };
            });
}
```

**Step 3**

Build and run.

and if any bad request come then you will see output like below-

[image]

Comment: This should be voted up to my mind as this uses **Problem Details** as specified in [RFC 7807](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807). One should always try to use standards where there's no explicit reason not to as to make using/ understanding APIs easier for all of us. Error handling with Problem Details is also described in the Microsoft Docs for ASP.NET Core. Please see [Produce a Problem Details Payload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-6.0#produce-a-problemdetails-payload-for-exceptions)