# Custom Validation Attribute for model C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, validation

I have a model

```
public class SendEmail
{
    public bool IsScheduled { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduleDate { get; set; }
    public List<ScheduleAttachement> ScheduleAttachement {get; set;}
}
public class ScheduleAttachement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Attachement { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do a custom validation to check if bool IsScheduled == true, ScheduleAttachement must contain a value. If not throw 400 bad request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (SendEmail.IsScheduled) 
{
  //true, in here you can check for a value:
  if(SendEmail.ScheduleAttachement == null || (!SendEmail.ScheduleAttachement.Any()))
  {
     //list is null or empty, throw error
  }
}
```

less code list null or empty check:

```
if (list?.Any() != true)
{
    //list is null or empty, throw error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your *controller* layer

```cs
var emailToCheck = new SendEmail();

if (!emailToCheck.IsScheduled && emailToCheck.ScheduleAttachement.Count() == 0) 
{
    return BadRequest();
}
```

If you want to add a custom message lookup this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61257445/18738885).

**Edit**

```cs
if (!emailToCheck.IsScheduled && emailToCheck.ScheduleAttachement?.Where(x => x.Attachment != null && x.Name != null).Count() > 0) 
{
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Comment: List<ScheduleAttachement> ScheduleAttachement always returns a count of 1. But attachment = null and Name = null;

Comment: @EmmanuelAgharaye see the new validation.