# How to return a full BadRequest response body with my own error

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

I am new to API's. I have consumed them, but never had to published my own until now.

I would like to have uniformity in all error responses. I would like to have all my responses (other than 200 range) look the same as the default error response, but when I add my own error, then only my error is returned in Postman.

### Illustration:

When a required parameter is not passed for example, there is an auto default response body which look like this:

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-118adfb731bbdb32e865873f70487da2-f5994dea1e69866a-00",
    "errors": {
        "Spec": [
            "The Spec field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Note that I am not validating fields and I did not generate the above error message.

When I return a `BadRequest()` response, in Postman I see a response body also containing the type, status, title and traceId:

API:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetList([FromQuery] SearchCriteria criteria)
{ 
    return BadRequest();  
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": 
}
```

BUT when I add an error message, then only my error message is returned in Postman:

API:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetList([FromQuery] SearchCriteria criteria)
{ 
    return BadRequest(error: new { error = "Unable to return list" });  
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "error": "Unable to return list"
}
```

How can I add my own error message and also still have the type, title, status, and traceId in the response so the user always knows what to expect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247934/add-a-message-to-your-http-400-bad-request-in-asp-net-core-3-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably easiest approach would be using `ValidationProblem`:

```cs
ModelState.AddModelError("return", "Unable to return List");
return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
```

Which produces the following response for me:

```json
{
   "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
   "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
   "status":400,
   "traceId":"00-4091c0b6419e8cc5d4e9cb1da3764f11-d2bc593ce1a51e0a-00",
   "errors":{
      "return":[
         "Unable to return List"
      ]
   }
}
```

Otherwise you might need to dabble with methods exposed by [`ProblemDetailsFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.problemdetailsfactory.createvalidationproblemdetails?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Just a pity that the title will always be "One or more validation errors occurred." when I would also want to use this response body for something like a SQL timeout. But I will also fiddle with the ProblemDetailsFactory as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a `JsonResult` with a custom class

`JsonResult` has a `StatusCode` property you can set

```
// model to return to client side
private class ReturnModel
{
    public string? message { get; set; }
    ...
}

// in controller method
return new JsonResult(new ReturnModel
{
    message = "..."
})
{
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
};
```

Comment: No, the whole point of "problem JSON" is that it's a standardized way of returning error responses and that you don't have to build your own response models.

Comment: @CodeCaster well since you know an alternative solution, why don't you post it ?

Comment: Because I'm on mobile and can't find a duplicate that quickly.

Comment: @Codingwiz Thank you. I actually thought about creating my own body that mimics the default response body. But it seems I will be able to use the ProblemDetailsFactory to achieve the expected result.